# Add a sub-property to a model's existing properties without turning them all into their own classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm not sure of the correct terminology but I'd like to add a "sub property"(?) to a segment of the properties within one of my model classes.  I understand I could update my model's existing properties into their own classes and then work with them from there, but I'm curious if there's a cleaner approach to this.

Here's a basic example of what I'm looking to do.  In this example, I have a model named "Book" and several book-related properties.  I'd like to add a "sub property" to some (not all) book properties (I'll name this "**RefreshOnClick**") to determine whether or not the property value should refresh the mvc page when the user updates the value on the web page (Again, for simplicity sake, this is just an example of what I'm trying to achieve & not my real code)

```
public class Book
{
      public int Id {get; set;}    
      public string Title {get; set;}    
      public string Author {get; set;}   
}
```

And here would be an example of the usage of the "RefreshOnClick" property

```
public Book()
{
     Title = "Game of Thrones";
     Author = "George RR Martin";

     Id.RefreshOnClick = null;
     Title.RefreshOnClick = true;
     Author.RefreshOnClick = false;
}
```

Thanks for any help.  Ultimately, this may not be feasible in the way I envisioned it, but figured I'd at least ask.

Thanks!

Comment: There are some flags/tags that can be applied to properties, as hint for various automatic systems. However I have no experience with the MVC pattern, so I can not tell you if there are any applicable ones.

Comment: "Attribute" seems to be the thing I was thinking about: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/#common-uses-for-attributes | It does take reflection to retreive the attribute (and do something based on the attribute being set), but that is kinda given if you want this to work without hardcoding.

Comment: I think you are having a classical design problem (Separation of Concerns) . You should think about trying to separate the domain model (the logical book) from the your view model (the stuff that is displayed by a specific technology/ui/..). once you have accomplished that, the property "RefreshOnClick" would be definitely in the specific view model, while you keep all of your business logic without knowledge of how it is displayed/clicked on, etc.. and could even display your book on uis that cant be clicked, by creating a different viewmodel for that